Upvoting under-researched questions
In re Brain Waves and Psilocybin Mushroom where the entire question was:

Is there any research on brain waves when on Psilocybin Mushrooms or LSD ? Thanks

Currently at +4/-0 votes, I'm kinda disappointed that no mod (or even other more regular site user) has left any comments on this question, until I did. I agree not biting newbies by downvoting such under-researched questions, an issue that has been discussed here in the past. But it looks to me like the pendulum has swung too much in the other direction. This question is more upvoted than a lot of recent questions here. I'm guessing it might have had something to do with the topic, but I'm not sure. I'd like to hear from from some people who upvoted it why they did that... or at least why upvoting such questions is a good idea.

I agree it is under researched, and under-specified. That said, it seems to be of interest to some people, and it has generated a fairly highly upvoted answer.

I remember almost down voting this question as it lacked initial research, but then, the question was so concise and quite precise, that I preferred simply not voting. I agree with your assessment though, up votes are not warranted. To counter-balance that I sometimes (maybe I will now) down vote highly up voted unwarranted questions.

I'm one of the upvoters. The reason was that hallucinogens are typically studied by brain imaging and when I saw the question I was immediately wondering if there would be literature on this. But yes, because I like the topic so much, I'm more inclined to hit the 'like' button. I'm just a human being :) I'll consider removing the upvote.

It is a valid point made by Fizz that we do have the standard to maintain that all questions need references to back motivation for asking, hence the close vote reason we recently added. Reading the question, it does have the air of “I have tried searching but cannot find anything” but it would be preferable to me for the questioner to state the fact as that would otherwise open things up to speculation which we also want to discourage in answers.  I missed that question when looking at new posts which is why I hadn’t commented.

Further, voting is scant here at this site, and upvotes are often hesitantly placed. I have a low vote-threshold in general to stimulate folks to come back and feel welcomed. Especially new users tend to get relatively easy upvotes from me. If misplaced, posts like this can help to re-set such voting thresholds.

Related: https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2511/7001
